# Draw a line animated continously

Tags: javascript, html

I want to draw a line in canvas continously. I've read from many source. There's an example draw them with svg and jquery.

What im trying to do is , draw a lines continously without jquery or svg like this example http://jsfiddle.net/UtmTh/. Is it possible?

Draw a line in track like this.

```
function draw_line(param1,.......) {
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    //just function to draw a lines
}
function line_track() {
      //set X & Y position start
      var x = 0;
      var y = 30;

      //set X & Y position finish
      //in here i want to create a finish position of line after animation run,
      like a jsfiddle example//

}
```

Help & teach me if my plan and design is gone wrong please.

Comment: What is wrong with the fiddle you have posted? Isn't exactly what you want to get?

Comment: In fiddle example that i posted use a library jQuery 1.7.1 sir.

Comment: if thats the only difference just use document.getElementById('paper') instead of $("#paper")[0]; and u dont need jquery for that example.If you need lines to be drawed after first finishes *continiously* than i can make a fiddle for that

Comment: Just change the the first line in the fiddle to `var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");` and remove the library as you don't need it.

Comment: Gurami, May you create a fiddle please? I need to learn more about canvas :). Thank you.

Comment: Diem13i, oh yeah. I don't know that i need is just simply change it. Now i learn something new, Thank you :)

Comment: @user4240518 You are welcome, and so that you know, to select an element in pure javascript you can use `document.getElementById("ID")`, while with jQuery you will have to use `$("#ID")`. To learn more about JavaScript and jQuery you should read both documentations, make some tutorials and testing.

Answer (score 0):

Like the comments says, the only use of JQuery library is the first line, getting the canvas element.

you can change this by using `var canvas = document.getElementById("paper");`.

In addition, if you repeat the drawing you don't have to perform `clearRect` and `moveTo` every draw cycle.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('paper');
var c = canvas.getContext("2d");

var startX = 50;
var startY = 50;
var endX = 100;
var endY = 100;
var amount = 0;

c.strokeStyle = "black";
c.moveTo(startX, startY);

setInterval(function() {
  amount += 0.05; // change to alter duration
  if (amount > 1) amount = 1;

  // lerp : a  + (b - a) * f
  c.lineTo(startX + (endX - startX) * amount, startY + (endY - startY) * amount);

  c.stroke();
}, 30);
```

```html
<canvas id="paper" width="500" height="500"></canvas>
```